# Issues Setting Up DNS on Linux BIND

Tags: dns

I am actually try to setup a DNS and adding an A record for an host that is locally  on the network . It looks it seems to have some issues .

```
[root@vxctf8500 ~]# nslookup N8500
Server:         10.209.194.15
Address:        10.209.194.15#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find N8500: No answer
```

Following The Configuration Files ::

named.conf

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//





options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;10.209.194.15; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query {any;};
    allow-recursion {any;};
    recursion no;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};


zone"vxctf8500.com" IN {
type master;
file "forward.vxctf8500.com";
allow-update { none; };
};
zone"0.209.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
type master;
file "reverse.vxctf8500.com";
allow-update { none; };
};
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Forward Zone ::

```
$TTL 1D
@   IN SOA ns1.vxctf8500.com. root.vxctf8500.com. (
                    0   ; serial
                    1D  ; refresh
                    1H  ; retry
                    1W  ; expire
                    3H )    ; minimum

@       IN NS       vxctf8500.com.
@       IN A     10.209.194.15


N8500           A       10.209.194.22
~
```

With , keeping recursion as YES, the query never completes and gives network error. However the local server resolves

```
[root@vxctf8500 ~]# nslookup vxctf8500.com
Server:         10.209.194.15
Address:        10.209.194.15#53

Name:   vxctf8500.com
Address: 10.209.194.15

[root@vxctf8500 ~]#
```

Tried With Following Again ::

```
$TTL 1D
@   IN SOA ns1.vxctf8500.com. root.vxctf8500.com. (
                    0   ; serial
                    1D  ; refresh
                    1H  ; retry
                    1W  ; expire
                    3H )    ; minimum

       IN NS       vxctf8500.com.
       IN A     10.209.194.15




ns1.vxctf8500.com IN A 10.209.194.15
N8500               IN   A       10.209.194.22



[root@vxctf8500 ~]# nslookup N8500
Server:         10.209.194.15
Address:        10.209.194.15#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find N8500: No answer

[root@vxctf8500 ~]#
```

Have also restart the named services.

Any Clues on Setting up Reverse Lookup ::

```
$TTL 1D
@   IN SOA  ns1.vxctf8500.com. root.vxctf8500.com. (
                    0   ; serial
                    1D  ; refresh
                    1H  ; retry
                    1W  ; expire
                    3H )    ; minimum
    NS  @
    A   127.0.0.1
    AAAA    ::1


       IN NS       10.209.194.15.


22      IN PTR      nclusters.vxctf8500.com
23      IN PTR      nclusters.vxctf8500.com
24      IN PTR      nclusters.vxctf8500.com
25      IN PTR      nclusters.vxctf8500.com
26      IN PTR      nclusters.vxctf8500.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in forward zone
you need to write

```
(fully qualified domain ) IN A (ip address of domain)
================================================

IN SOA 
ns1.vxctf8500.com. root.vxctf8500.com.
   (
                0   ; serial
                1D  ; refresh
                1H  ; retry
                1W  ; expire
                3H )    ; minimum

 IN NS       vxctf8500.com.
 IN A     10.209.194.15

ns1.vxctf8500.com.     IN     A       10.209.194.15
N8500.                 IN     A       10.209.194.22
```

:wq!  save  it

Comment: Thanks, For  Your Reply , It looks I still have some issues. Have added the  comment with latest results

Comment: Thanks , Got It now Add following                                           [root@vxctf8500 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search vxctf8500.com
nameserver localhost

Comment: Any Clues on setting the reverse lookup . Thanks

Comment: Opps !! Got it Worked out too !! Thanks